# Object Destructuring: no matching index signature for string

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a code that receives a string variable and gets the property with that name, but I attempted using object destructuring like so:

```js
export type Filter = {
  key: string
  value: string | number
  limit: number
  after: boolean
}
const pagFilter: Filter = { key: 'banana', value: 'banana2', limit: '10', after: 'id' }

const key = 'value'
const {[key]: obtainedValue} = pagFilter
```

This shows a `Type 'Filter' has no matching index signature for type 'string'` message for me. However, doing

```js
const key = 'value'
const obtainedValue = pagFilter[key]
```

does not.

In an attempt to fix this issue I tried to implement a type that has string as indexer

```js
export type FilterType = { [key: string]: string | number | boolean }
export class Filter implements FilterType {
  key: string
  value: string | number
  limit: number
  after: boolean
}
```

But the results were the same.

Am I really not allowed to do this? Is my syntax wrong?

My motivation was actually to use the spread operator to get a new object with the rest of the keys:

```js
const {[key]: obtainedValue, ...rest} = pagFilter
```

I'm using typescript 4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out!

```js
const key: keyof Filter = 'value'
const {[key]: obtainedValue} = pagFilter
```

It seems like I need to establish that key is of type keyof Filter for it to work!